# A request on the kernel of the function ”SpheroidalEigenvalue“ in Mathemitica 11

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion, implementation-details

I want to understand the algorithm of the function "SpheroidalEigenvlaue" in **Mathematica 11**, especially the code of the following command.
[image]

Then I will try to use this algorithm to reproduce the formulas (2.16a)-(2.16g) of arXiv:gr-qc/0511111. Could you give me some help? Thank you very much!

Comment: Isn't `SpheroidalEigenvalue[]` related only to what the paper calls $_0A_{lm}$ and not to the more general $_sA_{lm}$ that you're interested in?

Comment: Aren't *Mathematica*'s algorithms proprietary? But the series expansion of `SpheroidalEigenvalue[]` is presumably based on some result in the literature about scalar spheroidal harmonics.

Comment: @Ghoster I find the package "SpinWeightedSpheroidalHarmonics.m" is useful to compute the series expansion of spinweighted spheroidal eigenvalues. But I don't understand their code, it is likely based on some results in the literature.

Answer (score 1):

The standard reference is Moon/Spencer  "A Field theory handbook". It tabulates all separable systems of the classical PDE's, the separated ODE's  with solutions. Oblate and prolate spheroidal harmonics included. A PDF scan is downloadable over the internet.

Comment: Thanks! I think that it can be found by Mathematica.